# Claims Based Forms Authentication Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to authenticate a user using forms authentication in MVC 4 (I'm using RavenDB so I can't use the standard membership providers).  Then later I'm using the `User.IsInRole()` method or `AuthorizeAttribute` to verify the user is in a staff role.

Here's where I set the ticket on successful authentication (at the moment in `UserController.cs`):

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket =
    new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
        1,
        model.Email,
        DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
        false,
        model.Email);

string hashedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

HttpCookie cookie =
    new HttpCookie(
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
        hashedTicket);

HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Here's where I check the ticket for each request (`Global.asax`):

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

    if (authCookie != null)
    {
        var authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
        var user = this.UserService.GetUserByEmail(authTicket.Name);

        var identity = new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name, "Forms");

        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, user.Roles);

        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
    }
}
```

If I then put a debug point on one of my action methods (CalendarController.cs), I get `isStaff` equals `false`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var user = HttpContext.User;

    bool isStaff = user.IsInRole(Role.Staff);

    return View();
}
```

Just for completion (Roles.cs, just a temporary class to test things):

```
public static class Role
{
    public static string Staff
    {
        get { return "Staff"; }
    }

    public static string Manager
    {
        get { return "Manager"; }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help give me a point as to what I might be missing?  It looks as though the roles I set are disappearing by the time I get to the action method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks guys for helping me with this, what I've come up with (included below) works great!  It auto-logs users straight in through the login screen if they have a valid ticket (cookie) and also handles Claims based roles using the `ClaimsIdentity` and `ClaimsPrincipal` objects, without putting the roles in the user's cookie.  It also handles authentication in the `Global.asax.cs` file without having to resort to putting in custom authorize attributes.

*UserController.cs*

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    LoginViewModel model = new LoginViewModel();

    if ((HttpContext.User != null) &&
        (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    bool isAuthenticated = this.userService.IsPasswordValid(model.Email, model.Password);

    if (!isAuthenticated)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("AuthError", Resources.User.Login.AuthError);

        return View(model);
    }

    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, model.RememberUser);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

*Global.asax.cs*

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

    if (authCookie != null)
    {
        var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

        FormsIdentity formsIdentity = new FormsIdentity(ticket);

        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(formsIdentity);

        var user = this.UserService.GetUserByEmail(ticket.Name);

        foreach (var role in user.Roles)
        {
            claimsIdentity.AddClaim(
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }

        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

        HttpContext.Current.User = claimsPrincipal;
    }
}
```

Comment: as i said the main problem was you were using GenericIdentity instead of FormsIdentity

Comment: Using the `GenericIdentity` would work just fine.  The only reason I've used the `FormsIdentity` is that it has a more intention revealing constructor.  The solution was the Principal object being Claims based and using the correct one to be able to add roles, as claims, that would be recognised by MVC 4.

Comment: Is there any reason why you could not just replace most of the Account/Login code (from assigning the ticket onwards) with  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, createPersistentCookie: true);

Comment: Thanks @RhysC I've updated the answer.  `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()` appears be a much better way of performing everything that I was previously doing by hand.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Raven I am assuming you made your own custom MembershipProvider and RoleProvider; and modified the web.config to use them.  You should have an entry similar to this:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="namespace.MyMembershipProvider, providerAssemblyName" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="namespace.MyRoleProvider, providerAssemblyName" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

If you are using .NET Framework version 4.5 it uses claims-based security and you do not need to store the roles in the cookie. Instead roles are just another claim that is stored in the [ClaimsPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.aspx).  All principals now inherit from ClaimsPrincipal and it is stored for the users session in

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User as ClaimsPrincipal
```

If your membership and role providers are setup correctly ASP.NET should use them to populate the roles in ClaimsPrincipal and then check the claims when you check **IsInRole**.

You can also retrieve roles from the ClaimsPrincipal for roles like this.

```
principal.FindAll(ClaimTypes.Role).Select(p => p.Value);
```

And you can add roles to a ClaimsPrincipal like this.

```
List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
foreach (string role in roles)
   claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Forms"));
```

Now you can just set your cookie after authentication like this.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
```

Comment: I'd read that making your own membership provider was quite heavyweight, a bit out dated and that I could achieve the same thing with forms based authentication.  I'd looked at some GitHub projects where people had attempted something like a RavenDB membership provider and they seemed a bit incomplete.

Comment: There are some issues with the membership provider model, but the advantage to using it is that ASP.NET handles most of the security framework for you.  You do not need a complete membership and role provider to have it work correctly in ASP.NET. Many of the methods are not required and I have not seen a good description of what the minimum is. One of the complaints of the provider model.  If you do not use it you still can leverage using the ClaimsPrincipal to store your roles instead of the cookie.  I think if you do it this way you can still reuse the default AuthorizeAttribute.

Comment: Cheers, I've a few ideas to work through now, so I'll +1 both answers.  The current model I use works great for authentication, just not roles, so I'm not far off.  If I can use this `ClaimsPrincipal` it might be the answer.

Comment: I think that membershipprovider is not worth it. Mainly becouse it is a pain to integrate it with other data access or add custom properties to User class

Answer (score 2):

you are not creating the FormsAuthenticationTicket inserting roles info:

```
        var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                1, //ticket version
                userName,
                DateTime.Now,
                DateTime.Now.Add(timeout), //timeout
                true, //persistent cookies
                roles,// <---ROLES not model.Email
                FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
```

------EDIT-----

Forget what I said: i think you are calling IsInRole() too early or user.Roles has the wrong value (maybe spaces in strings: isinrole uses  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) or you should use FormsIdentity instead of GenericIdentity.

What the debugger says?

For reference: http://pastebin.com/jkqqcg28
(this is the starting model I use for handling authentication)

Comment: Are you sure this parameter is for user roles? In the MSDN documentation they define this parameter as 'user-specific data to be stored with the ticket'.  I've seen this example elsewhere and I wanted to not store the user's roles in the ticket (which ends up an encrypted cookie on the client).

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips This is an easy and handy way to do it if you want to use Context.User.IsInRole.  If you don't want to store it in the ticket you should query the db with the username to know the role. Anyway FormsAuthenticationTicket is encrypted and enough safe.

Comment: Cheers, I might consider it, although it might behave oddly when I change a user's roles on the system.  I'm still looking at why the `User` I access in the action method, doesn't have the same roles that I am setting in `global.asax`.

Comment: this is a good point. I usually refresh the FormsAuthenticationTicket when the session expires to limit that possibility. Anyway looking to your code maybe your problem is due to calling user.IsInRole to early. Try to set HttpContext.Current.User after HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

Comment: Cheers, I've changed the ticket to use persistent cookies, the weird part is, when I debug the `User` object (an `IPrincipal`) I don't see the Roles anywhere within the object graph.  I'll have a look through you're example tonight.

Comment: you don't see Roles because it is a private field. you should try to stepin with resharper or reflector