# Implementing role based authorization in MVC and Web API with custom table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization, asp.net-web-api2

I have inherited an application with database. The database has following tables related to authentication and authorization.

**User Table**

UserName

Password

UserTypeId

**UserType Table**

UserTypeId

UserTypeDesc

The User Type table stores the roles for the user e.g. Admin, Editor, etc.

If I want to implement authorization like below

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin, Editor")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetOrders()
        {
          //Code here
        }
```

Where and what should I code so that the roles are available to the authorize attribute ?

**Edit**

I already have a database. So I cannot use the AspNetUserRoles or AspNetRoles tables. I need to set the roles using my custom tables.

**Edit2**

As asked by @Nkosi, here is code snippet of how authentication is implemented. The actual implementation calls the business layer service and performs encryption and other stuff but I have simplified the snippet

```
public HttpResponseMessage Authenticate(User user)
{ 
    var isValid = myRepository.Exists(a => a.UserName == user.UserName &&       a.Password == user.Password);
   if(isValid)
  {
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName,false);
   }
}
```

This method is called from the login page where user enters the UserName and Password

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are asking.

Comment: I have added more text. I hope it is clear now

Comment: Roles already support attribute authorization. Are you asking How to add roles to table? Its still unclear. Also in attribute, you have to type roles.

Comment: When you authenticate a user query the roles for that user and include it when creating the claims principle for that user. that way when the authorize action filter query using `IsInRole` it will know the roles from your custom table

Comment: How do you authenticate your users

Comment: @Nkosi, I use forms authentication. I use the SetAuthCookie method. Can you provide an example of how and where to create the claims principle ?

Comment: @devanalyst include a snippet of how you authenticate users and I'll see if I can assist you with where you can implement it.

Comment: @Nkosi, I have included a code snippet as "Edit2" in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using these Answers for reference

[Having Trouble with Forms Authentication Roles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14615211/5233410)

[FormsAuthentication Roles without Membership](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16934752/5233410)

After having set the auth cookie on login like you did originally,

you do the following in your `Global.asax.cs`

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

    if (authCookie != null)
    {
        var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

        FormsIdentity formsIdentity = new FormsIdentity(ticket);

        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(formsIdentity);

        //get the user from your custom tables/repository
        var user = myUserRepository.GetUserByEmail(ticket.Name);
        if(user!=null){
            var userTypeId = user.UserTypeId;
            var role = myUserTypeRepository.GetUserTypeById(userTypeId);
            if(role != null) {
                //Assuming the roles for the user e.g. Admin, Editor, etc. 
                // is in the UserTypeDesc property
                claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.UserTypeDesc));
            }
        }    
        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal ;
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null) {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = claimsPrincipal ;
        }
    }
}
```

The nice thing about how they implemented it is that it handles Claims based roles using the `ClaimsIdentity` and `ClaimsPrincipal` objects, without putting the roles in the user's cookie. It also handles authentication in the `Global.asax.cs` file without having to resort to putting in custom authorize attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Your question was very easy. You just need to sync these 2 tables with AspNetUserRoles and AspNetRoles tables respectively. Actually, Authorize attribute by default checks these two tables. So your roles need to reflect in them. These tables are made by default by EF if you select MVC template project.

Comment: I already have an existing database so I cannot use the AspNetUserRoles or AspNetRoles tables. I need to do it for my custom tables

Comment: Your application doesn't have these tables? It is possible to change there names, these tables can exist with a different name

Comment: Every MVC application which uses Identity will have these tables or corresponding tables with different name